# ERROR: gcloud crashed (ModuleNotFoundError): No module named 'distutils.spawn'

Tags: gcloud

I have been deploying my service on App Engine for a long time now and never had an issue until today.

**Command to Deploy**

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

**Output**

```
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
Building and pushing image for service [default]
ERROR: gcloud crashed (ModuleNotFoundError): No module named 'distutils.spawn'
```

I just deployed this morning with no issues and randomly when I tried to redeploy now I get the above error. Hopefully someone can help figure out what caused this issue.

For info:

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 4
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

**Gcloud version**

```
$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 341.0.0
alpha 2021.05.14
beta 2021.05.14
bq 2.0.68
core 2021.05.14
gsutil 4.62
minikube 1.20.0
skaffold 1.23.0
```

Comment: What is the version of `gcloud`?

Comment: I've added the output of `gcloud --version` to the issue :)

Comment: I think I found a work around or something `export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python` did it for me, I can finally deploy with the crash. I don't fully understand what changed, seems that gcloud tried to run using python3 which failed and if I force it to use python2 it is happy. Either way if someone has a better explanation please let me know.

Comment: The Cloud SDK includes its own Python distribution. Your workaround means you selected to use a different distribution. Uninstall the Cloud SDK and then reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same exact problem.

Building and pushing image for service [default]
ERROR: gcloud crashed (ModuleNotFoundError): No module named 'distutils.spawn'

This issue seemed to be in the snap install of google-cloud-sdk in Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (You can select it pre-installed during the ISO setup.. DONT)

I was getting this in 18.04 as well

FINALLY solved it..

But.. I had to make sure I did not snap install google-cloud-sdk

I also..

sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

Then I made sure the snap install was not installed.  (After a fresh install of Ubuntu).  Sense I use dockerfiles it's easy for me to zap a dev environment and get it back.

But Id imagine if you can't zap your os and make sure not to let the OS put it's snap install of google-cloud-sdk.. You could snap remove google-cloud-sdk  and then hunt for all it's configuration files.. And remove them.

At that point

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb

Follow that... I did so exactly... FINALLY seemed to work.  I used the apt install route they explain.. NOT the snap.

I tried all the pip install sudo apt-get install python3-distutils  Till I was blue in the face... NADA.

somehow.. The Snap being present puts PATH settings that use the wrong distutils.

On my box now that I search for it.. In Totally fresh OS state... No Snap install and going through exactly the cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb work..

Here is distutils everywhere on my box in Ubuntu 20.03.2 LTS

```
$ sudo find / -name distutils

/snap/lxd/19188/lib/python2.7/distutils
/snap/core18/1944/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils
/snap/core18/1944/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils
/snap/core18/1944/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils
/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils
/usr/lib/python3.9/distutils
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils
```

Note.. There's no google-cloud-sdk in the snap!!

The gcloud app deploy FINALLY works!!   Passes the part where it starts to deploy.

But as the others in this.. It happened completly random.

All I can guess is......  Something clobered distutils as an update somewhere and started pointing to a garbage path.

Make sure you search for distutils find out where it is.. what's referencing it.. Somewhere in that mess you can fix it.

---

One thing I was able to discover is this problem will come default from 20.04.2.

I downloaded the most recent iso.. thinking it was an 18.04 issue.

Installed it fresh into Virtual Box.. And got exactly this same issue.  So my solution fix (no SNAP).. Is against a totally clean 20.04.2 brand spanking new Ubuntu LTS VM.  Default everything.

===============

Regarding the random one day it worked.. the next it didn't...

Here's the thing about snaps in Ubuntu:

https://www.google.com/search?q=Do+snap+packages+update+automatically%3F&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS834US834&ei=ygynYJGRIo3f-gSLzb3YDg&oq=Do+snap+packages+update+automatically%3F&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCAghEBYQHRAeUJ-TCVifkwlgj5kJaABwAXgAgAFziAHVAZIBAzEuMZgBAKABAqABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiRnrfXz9nwAhWNr54KHYtmD-sQ4dUDCA4&uact=5

"Do snap packages update automatically?

Snaps update automatically, and by default, the snapd daemon checks for updates 4 times a day. Each update check is called a refresh."

so that's how it randomly broke if you used a snap

Comment: I have gcloud-sdk installed via snap, soo this would make complete sense. I'll uninstall the snap package and install the recommended way. I'll let you know if this works (i think it should).

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, on my case this was the solution:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
```